# Can you identify this species name?

Tags: species-identification

[image]
I found this animal in Thanjavur.. It is millipede.. But I don't find out this species name..

Answer (score 0):

Consider this: [Orthomorpha coarcata](https://www.google.com/search?q=orthomorpha+coarctata&oq=orthomorpha+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3j69i60.4036j0j7&client=ms-android-xiaomi-rev2&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)
That's the closest I got, yes this millipede is found here in Odisha too
! [Black and yellow millipede](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxfDf.jpg)